# creating multi lingual website

Tags: javascript, html, css, multilingual

I am trying to figure out how to develop a multi-lingual website. My background in HTML, JS, CSS is not that broad (I have started only a week ago), therefore my understanding of this may not be the best.

For our example we will be creating three language mutations:

- English (main one)
- Spanish
- French.

Here is what I have come across when I started searching for this under uncle Google.

- **The longest solution I can imagine**: Create three folders named `en`, `es`, `fr`. These will contain the replica of the original webpage (e.g. `index.html`), but will be translated to respective language. Then on the top panel, you will have a button which upon clicking it will redirect used to a different folder (link is hard coded here). This solution is feasible if we are dealing with very small websites (with a few pages).
- Second option I have found, was using WordPress plugins (found quite a few of those). Unfortunately, this solution is not viable, as I am not using wordpress to create a website.
- Next option (which I believe would be the best), is to have one page for all language mutations, but instead of real text, you would insert some attribute with the key, which will determine what phrase should be inserted here. It could look like `data-toTranslate('sTitle')` (making this up). The question now would be, where would you store your texts? One option would be into a database, but I have not worked with them (under websites), therefore I would prefer something like a text file / csv file / or something like this. The problem I have with this solution (except the fact that I don't know how to do it yet :) ) is that I am not quite sure how website would react to this in terms of loading time. Maybe this is the best solution for a developer, yet the worst for the website?

Any comments, links or suggestions which would point me in the right direction would be more than welcome!

**EDIT:** as this question may seem too broad, I will try to trim it a bit down.

As I believe the option number three would be the best, then I would like to know the following things:

- 1) What do I need to create when I want to store simple key - value pairs (such as in this translation)? If I were in C#, I would e.g. create either simple XML or CSV file and I would parse it during runtime.
- 2) Can I achieve this with a simple JavaScript, or do I need to create some specific controllers / directives with AngularJS?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the english version of the website statically, as this is the main language. You should have a separate ID for every text element (and don't use obe word ids such as "a" "b" etc., so you can easily fibd them later.

Have a file on your server (text file works too) with the ids of fhe text tags, and the text in a format like

```
welcome-text | ["Welcome to the website" in Spanish]
-------------
Etc...
```

(Note: yoh need to store the translated sentences, but I don't know Spanish nor France)

Name your file to something like Spanish.txt.

When the page loads, download this file with javascript trough AJAX (this is where the static english version kicks in as a fallback), loop trough the text file and set the texts to the translated version.

You can of course use PHP with MysQL too, but I thought it is a bit overkill for 2 languages.

And yes, this can be done with 100% pure javascript, not even JQuery is required.

Comment: sounds great, one more thing - what exactly should I be looking for in AJAX? I have never used it before.

Comment: @Robert J. XMLHTTPRequests, http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 1):

I normally using PHP to handle this multilingual. When every moment user view the website, it will set the default language to ENG. But, when the user select other language as the website display language, the website will reload and the PHP code will call the respective language folder to display all the selected language on the website. So, I think you should having few language folder, then dynamic calling each of the folder to get the keywords words and display it.